Issues with Expo Go and EAS Build for Development Purposes
I am currently working on a React Native project using Expo and I am facing some issues with the development process. I used to work with Expo Go for development, which allowed fast refreshing after changes. However, after creating a eas.json file to build a preview APK, I can't seem to make Expo Go work as before.
Because I couldn't see any fast refresh, I uninstalled my app preview APK on my device, in a attempt to force Expo Go to bundle from source code.
Here's the error I get when I run yarn android from now, which is confusing to me:
CommandError: No development build (com.tiedsiren.tiedsiren) for this project is installed. Please make and install a development build on the device first.

And here is my eas.json file:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.8.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": false,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "release": {
      "distribution": "store"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

It seems that I am now required to build every single time I make a modification, which is a very long process that I obviously want to avoid for development.
Could anyone provide some guidance on how to properly use Expo Go and EAS for development?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

i had to face a similar problem so to see your modifications reflect in code, what you do is:

reinstall your apk
run npx expo start
and upon its asking, press s to switch back to expo go version

please let me know if it works for you.

I had something very similar happening to me with the following error on the Expo Go app: Uncaught Error: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
I tried a lot of things, and to my surprise, the solution was to log in into the Expo Go app with the same account as the one used to build the app.
I then selected the project from the Expo Go app with Expo started in my computer in tunnel mode. I don't think how you load the project makes a difference, but I'll leave it here just in case.
